# Evaluation of values and an OR statement in R

Tags: r, logic

As part of an `R` program I create matrices patients, `invited` and `missinrow` and scalars `numdrop` and `maxses`. These all exist and are properly created.

I then try this line

```
else if (invited[iPatient, iSession] >= maxses |
  missinrow[iPatient,iSession] >= (numdrop+1 )) {
    patients[iPatient,iSession] <- 'D'}
```

The part before the `|` works perfectly, the part after the `|` doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I've tried making this line into two statements, I've tried `||` instead of `|`, I've stared at it for hours.
Help!
Thanks

**Added 6/28/11**
The program reads parameters from another file and creates data. But here is some output:

```
invited[1:5, 1:14]
```

gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10    11    12    12
[2,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10    11    12    12
[3,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10    11    12    12
[4,]    0    0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7     8     9    10    11
[5,]    0    0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7     8     9    10    11
```

which is fine

```
missinrow[1:5, 1:14]
```

gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10     0     0     0     0
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10     0     0     0     0
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
[4,]    0    0    1    2    0    0    1    2    3     4     5     6     7     0
[5,]    0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8     9    10    11    12
```

also fine, but

```
patients[1:5, 1:14]
```

gives

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,] "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"   "A"   "S"   "D"   "D"  
[2,] "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"   "A"   "A"   "D"   "D"  
[3,] "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "A"  "S"  "A"  "A"  "A"   "S"   "S"   "D"   "D"  
[4,] "NA" "W"  "S"  "S"  "A"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"   "S"   "S"   "S"   "A"  
[5,] "NA" "W"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"  "S"   "S"   "S"   "S"   "S"
```

and we see that the cells where `invited` is higher than `maxses` (which is 12) are all `D`, as they should be, but those where `missinrow` is higher than `numdrop + 1` (which is 4 +1) are not `D`.

Comment: I tried running the code and the `missinrow[iPatient,iSession]` test works perfectly for me. Is it possible `missinrow` doesn't have the data you expect in it? Are `iPatient` and `iSession` the right numbers?

Comment: it will help if you create some sample data and expected results and add this to your question.

Comment: Try examining debugging at the point when the error arises. You can do this by setting `options(error = recover)`

Comment: Thanks @owen @Andrie and @nullglob  I need to learn some more debugging tools. options looks like one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code including your expression

```
invited   <- 10 * matrix(12:1, nrow=3)
missinrow <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3)
patients  <- matrix(rep("A",12), nrow=3)
maxses    <- 100
numdrop   <- 7 

for (iPatient in 1:3) { 
    for (iSession in 1:4) {
        if (iPatient==iSession) { patients[iPatient,iSession] <- 'B'}
        else if (invited[iPatient, iSession] >= maxses |
          missinrow[iPatient,iSession] >= (numdrop+1 )) {
            patients[iPatient,iSession] <- 'D'} 
                          }
                      }
```

Looking at the three matrices

```
> invited
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  120   90   60   30
[2,]  110   80   50   20
[3,]  100   70   40   10
> missinrow
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> patients
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "B"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
[2,] "D"  "B"  "D"  "D" 
[3,] "D"  "A"  "B"  "D"
```

I would say the `else if` statement was working as expected, and that the "D"s on the left hand side of `patients` corresponded to the second  `else if` condition.